# How to force Azure Websites guest OS version update/choose

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure Websites are running on VMs, fully managed by MS. Guest OS version is also chosen by MS.

But sometimes some OS updates are critical for me (for example timezone updates, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590155/wrong-azure-website-server-timezone-data)). 
According to [Azure Guest OS Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee924680.aspx) (and [RSS feed](http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/3.0/msdntn/WindowsAzureOSUpdates)) new OS versions are already released. These OS patch is included in Guest OS versions released at Now 5 (and later) - my Cloud Services have correct timezone data.

But my "test" website (from [prev. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590155/wrong-azure-website-server-timezone-data)) shows that its Guest OS still have no timezone patch. I think website is still running on VM with old GuestOS.

Is there any way to view which GuestOS version website is running on (from code)? I know hot to view GuestOS version for Cloud Services, but not for website.

Why VMs that runs websites still not updated? How often they are updated?

Can I someway force my website to run/migrate to 'fresh' guest OS? I think 'no', but maybe...

Comment: Guest OS is a concept that relates to Azure Cloud Services (Web and Worker Roles) and not to Websites which are a different form of hosting. If you host on a Web Role you can specify the Guest OS and version using the Cloud Services Definition.

Comment: Ok, lets call it 'Host OS' instead 'Guest OS', but it still some MS Server OS. When (how often) updates are applied to it ? Why updates, issued more than month ago, are still not applied.